# Are multiple tabs secure for submiting forms?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, forms

I am trying to make an online shop that allow users to spend minimum time on checkout.

They have to select from 4 possibilities which i can make it two ways.

First i can make a select field with jquery to update the next fields from database or i can make 4 tabs and each of them have diferent forms that take data from database.

Bassicaly i want to ask what should i choose and i don't really know how to do it with jquery so if you suggest that way please post a tutorial if available cause i didn't found one related to updating select fields from database.

Second i need to know if choosing the tabs should cause any problem of security on posting form or something like that.

i use CI2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using tabs won't affect the security of form posts because the elements are still contained within the form. Other than that I'm not quite sure what your asking?

Comment: Well basicaly i would have 4 forms and i want to know if they can interfeer one with the other since they will have the same name and there will be a hidden field that specify which tab have been submited.

Comment: If you have 4 forms on a page without tabs, and they submit correctly. Then they would work exactly the same with tabs. I don't not much about form submission but if you test it without tabs initially and it works, then adding tabs won't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I think I mis-understood your question. Why would you not use a Select field?

Comment: I think is simplier with tabs and i don't really know how to render data from database to populate the rest of select fields when i select the first option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats true, sorry. Here a code fragment from one of my projects

```
$('select.myfield').change(function(){

    var data = $('select.myfield').val();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'Url/to/your/script',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                //validate
                //change form fields

            }
    });
});
```

in your PHP method, you need return json_encode($data);

Comment: Thank you, this should help me i will implement it.